# Trouble with handling URI data (attempting to load direct to DB)

Tags: python, rest

I am working on a script to make an API call to a vendor.  The initial call returns a JSON list containing a list of URIs to get my data from.  When I connect to one of those URIs and retrieve that data, it is not JSON being returned, its comma delimited.  I can write this to a CSV file without a problem.

What I want to do is write it directly to my DB and therein lies the issue.  The rows are \n delimited and the fields are comma delimited and sometimes they are enclosed with a double quote, sometimes not.  Compounding the issue is some of the fields enclosed by double quotes have commas in them.

I need to be able to get the headers (which i have figured out) so I can use them for the field names to write to the DB (the vendor likes to change the order and occasionally exclude fields)  I cannot just dump the data into the table since there could be new or missing or out of order fields.  I've tried a number or methods and nothing is splitting this string correctly.

Here is an example of one row in the dataset:
 `"July Test", "", 'nothing to see here', "1043 E Main, Dallas, TX 40565", more random crap`

What I need is
 `"July Test", "", "nothing to see here", "1043 E Main, Dallas, TX 40565", "more random crap"`

Here is my HTTP call and handling the return.  Maybe I should do it differently?  I've commented out everything I have tried and failed with.

## Takes the URL for the most current file and opens connection and exports data

```
    site= str(x["full_csv_url"])
    hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    req = Request(site,headers=hdr)
    req.add_header('Authorization', token)

    with urlopen(req) as x:
        data = x.read().decode('utf-8')        



try:
        #for i in data.split('\n'):
        #    list = print([i])
        list_of_lines = data.splitlines(True)
        
        new_split_data = []
                            
        for i in range(1, 2):   #nlines
            ith_line = str(list_of_lines[i])
            ith_line = ith_line.replace("\n","")
            ith_line = ith_line.replace("\r","")
            
            
            """Split a python-tokenizable expression on comma operators"""
            #compos = [-1] # compos stores the positions of the relevant commas in the argument string
            #compos.extend(t[2][1] for t in generate_tokens(StringIO(ith_line).readline) if t[1] == ',')
            #compos.append(len(ith_line))
            #new_ith_line = [ ith_line[compos[i]+1:compos[i+1]] for i in xrange(len(compos)-1)]
            
            #for i in new_ith_line:
            #    print[i]
            print(ith_line)
            print("New Line")
            print("New Line")
            #new_ith_line = re.split(r', (?=(?:"[^"]*?(?: [^"]*)*))|, (?=[^",]+(?:,|$))', ith_line)
            new_ith_line = list(csv.reader(ith_line, delimiter=','))
            #new_ith_line = re.split(r',(?=")', ith_line)
            #new_ith_line = new_ith_line.replace("'\"","'")
            #new_ith_line = new_ith_line.replace("\"'","'")
            print(new_ith_line)
            ##Didnt work-- split fields with commas between double quotes
            ##newstr = ith_line.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)")
            
            # Didnt work, only returned 1st 2 columns
            #print(pp.commaSeparatedList.parseString(ith_line).asList())
            
            # Didnt work, returned error
            #newStr = [ '"{}"'.format(x) for x in list(csv.reader([ith_line], delimiter=',', quotechar='"'))[0] ]
            #print(newStr)
               
            #print(ith_line)
            #each_line = data.body.getText().partition("\n")[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a regex expression which worked for my situation with a small tweak.

This code:  new_list = re.findall(r'(?:[^,"]|"(?:\.|[^"])*")+', list)

Gave me:  "July Test", "", "nothing to see here", "1043 E Main, Dallas, TX 40565", "more random crap"

I was then able to create a list and load to the DB.